# Why is Stanford NLP nesting other phrases inside verb phrases?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I noticed a full parse nests other phrases inside verb phrases like here (although Noun Phrases seem to be standalone)

```
(ROOT\n  (S\n    (NP (DT The) (JJ quick) (JJ brown) (NN fox))\n    (VP (VBD jumped)\n      (PP (IN over)\n        (NP (DT the) (JJ lazy) (NN dog.))))))
```

When I run a simple chunking via Apache OpenNLP, verb phrases are standalone like here

```
[NP The_DT quick_JJ brown_JJ fox_NN ] [VP jumped_VBD ] [PP over_IN ] [NP the_DT lazy_JJ dog_NN ] ._.
```

Although, Apache OpenNLPs full parse is nesting verb phrases too. (https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.parser.parsing.cmdline)

```
(TOP (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ quick) (JJ brown) (NN fox) (NNS jumps)) (PP (IN over) (NP (DT the) (JJ lazy) (NN dog))) (. .)))
```

Is it correct that Stanford NLP nests other phrases inside Verb Phrases?

Comment: Parsing ≠ Chunking

Comment: That is clear :) Still, only verb phrases seem to be nested during parsing. Other phrases are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://udel.edu/~heinz/classes/2012/4-667/materials/JM2008-Chap12.pdf

Usually everything but the subject is in the verb phrase.